# SOCI external symbol unresolved "struct soci::mysql_backend_factory const soci::mysql"

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, soci

I'm really confused, i'm stuck with this problem, i hope you can help me :

I use : Windows 8.1, Visual Studio Express 2013 and SOCI 3.2.2

I have compiled both libsoci_mysql and libsoci_core and linked them into my project, but when i launch the compilation this error appear :

Error   1   error LNK2001: external symbol unresolved "struct soci::mysql_backend_factory const soci::mysql" (?mysql@soci@@3Umysql_backend_factory@1@B) dbConnection.obj    Server

I'm a little bit lost with Window, but i'm praticly sure libsoci_mysql.lib is found and (i have open the .lib with GNU emacs) contains the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a [known problem](https://www.mail-archive.com/soci-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00929.html) with MSVC. The proposed workaround is to replace `soci::mysql` usage with `*soci::factory_mysql()`.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else stumbles upon this I ran into a similar problem where `odbc_option_driver_complete` was undefined.

The issue was that this is defined in the header as an external and implemented in DLL. By default when building the DLL the code sets up a #define to eventually set `__declspec(dllexport)` for the external.

However, when you include the header in your code it does **NOT** by default set `__declspec(dllimport)` for the external! To trigger this **you must `#define SOCI_DLL` in YOUR project** to set this up.

Ideally your should set this in Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocesor Definitions

Comment: Thank you! Just saved me some time.